# Pass a props in the ":to" attribute of a router link in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-props

I'm having an issue to create a router-link in vue and passing it a route name as a props...
What I want to do basically is this :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link :to="myProps">Login</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: componentName,
    props: {
      myProps: {
        type: String,
        default: '{ name: login }'
      }     
    }
  }
</script>
```

Login is of course difined in my router. But as I give the route as a props, I get redirected to `/%7B%20name:%20'login'%20%7D`. Do you know of any trick to get around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get from the default value is a string, but you need an object. Try in this way:

```js
props: {
  myProps: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({name: 'login'})
  }
}
```

Here's more about props default value: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation